# Creating CSV file in java, which carachter of a string i should replace for a correct CSV output?

Tags: java, string, csv, replace

Before writing this i searched for any documentation that tell me which characters will corrupt the final csv that is generated from java. I didn't find anything good and complete. I make a method in my code to replace all possibile minimum characters from a string before create a csv:

```
    public static String getPureNote(String dirtyNote) {
    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < dirtyNote.length(); i++) {
        char c = dirtyNote.charAt(i);
        if (c == '\n') {//new line make a new line in my csv and i want just to stay in a single cell
            s.append(" ");
        } else if (c == '\r') {
            s.append(" ");
        } else if (c == '\t') {//make a huge tab 
            s.append(" ");
        } else if (c == ';') {//the input continue in a adjacent cell and don't stay in a single one
            s.append(",");
        } else {
            s.append(c);
        }
    }

    return s.toString();

}
```

String Example and CSV look like:

```
 ok (implementing the method getPureNote):
 Com  Code  Desc   Struct   Note
 62   001   first  1         first structure on  
 63   002   second 2         second structure off
 ko (if after structure on note is /n character and not implementing the        method): 
 Com   Code  Desc   Struct  Note
 62   001   first  1         first structure 
 on  
 63   002   second 2         second structure 
 off
```

This method is ok for now but i want to know which characters i should replace/remove always from string before creating a csv file? I can't test all possibile character that will corrupt my csv file. Final users will open it on double click and not importing it in Excel. 
Thank you

Comment: Who/what will be consuming this CSV file?  And will the characters your code replaces have a special meaning in the CSV file?

Comment: You can either read and implement [the official specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) or you can make a better use of your time and rely on an existing, well-tested, csv library.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This CSV is a report from some query on DB and user can download it. Is generated from a servlet. Yes, the character corrupt my csv (some lines where is /n goes in a new line and not inside a cell, i edit my question now to esplain)

Comment: Hmmm...if you don't know which characters will spook the CSV, do you know which characters will _not_ spook the CSV?  I.e. could you create a whitelist of allowed characters?

Comment: @assylias thank you, i will read that RFC.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes (i.e. `"`). You can probably replace those by single quotes (i.e. `'`).

However, if your value contains a delimiter already (i.e. the comma: `,`) you will have to enclose the entire value within quotes at the end.

Looking at your code, you should do this:

```
boolean wrapInQuotes = false;
int recordStart = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dirtyNote.length(); i++) {
    char c = dirtyNote.charAt(i);
    ... // your original code here
    } else if (c == ',') { //value contains comma, we need to put it in quotes.
        s.append(c);
        wrapInQuotes = true;
    } else if (c == ';') { //looks like you want to create a new record
        if(wrapInQuotes){
            s.insert(recordStart, '"'); //puts a quote before the field
            s.append('"'); //puts the closing quote after the field
        }
        s.append(",");
        recordStart = s.length();
        wrapInQuotes = false; //starts over
    } else if (c == '"') {
        s.append('\''); //replace double quotes by single quotes.
    } else {
        s.append(c);
    }

    if(wrapInQuotes){
        s.insert(recordStart, '"'); //puts a quote before the field
        s.append('"'); //puts the closing quote after the field
    }
}
```

I didn't actually test this but it should do the trick. As you can see processing CSV is not exactly straightforward. If things get too tricky or slow maybe try using a CSV library such as [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to do the job for you (I'm the author of this library by the way).

Hope this helps

Comment: I will test it asap